# "message": "Illegal string offset 'product_id'", "exception": "ErrorException",

Tags: php, json, associative

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

```
        // Decode the received JSON and store into $obj
        $obj = json_decode($json,true);

        foreach($obj as $product){
          $product_id = $product['product_id'];
          $data=array("product_id"=>$product_id);
          DB::table('order_products')->insert($data); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What's inside the `$product` in your foreach-loop?

**Example:**

If its `array( product_id => 1 )`, the result of `$product['product_id']` would be `1`.

But if there's an error and `$product` is for example `{"product_id":1}` (a string instead of array), the result of `$product['product_id']` would be an error.

**Possible Fix:**

You can try `$product = json_decode($product, true);` inside your foreach-loop, maybe `$product` isn't decoded and still a string, so this would fix your problem.